# Google tag manager how to split an array and send the data seperate with one tag

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Im trying to extract parameters from the URL. Then send that data to google analytics via GTM. Using only one tag instead of having mulitple tags for each parameter.

```
 website.com/index?searched=data%7Cdata%7Cdata
```

The data needs to be seperated. So I've created a variable that seperates each paramater.

```
function () { 
  var x = {{URL Query}}.split("|");
  var z = x.slice(1, -1);
  return z; 
}
```

And a trigger that picks up on click.

I'm fairly new to google tag manager, and i'm unsure of the process to do this. Should I work with Datalayers or do a loop with Custom HTML tag? But then i'm not sure what the code is to send my data to google analytics.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to create multiple variables if you want to capture different parameters in the URL to separate dimensions in Google Analytics. When looking at your code I can see that you want to get the last value separated by "|". Take your code, place it within a "Custom Javascript" variable and then in your Google Analytics tag you can just map the variable to whatever dimension you have set up for this purpose.

Lastly, if you want to pick up more parameters in the URL, just create a a new Custom javascript variable, capture the parameter then map it to another dimension in the Google Analytics tag.

Hope this helps.